# KeyboardAvoidingView not applying keyboardVerticalOffset when nested

Tags: react-native

When I use KeyboardAvoidingView on its own it works fine but once i nest it inside another component it doesn't bump the keyboard up for IOS anymore. Anyone know of a solution?

current component tree:

GestureRecognizer component 
-> Animated.View component 
   -> KeyboardAvoidingView component